# How to get a df with the first non nan value onwards?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this df:

```
       CODE      DATE     TMAX   TMIN   PP
0      000130 1991-01-01  NaN    NaN   0.0
1      000130 1991-01-02  31.2   NaN   0.0
2      000130 1991-01-03  32.0   21.2  0.0
3      000130 1991-01-04  NaN    NaN   0.0
4      000130 1991-01-05  NaN    22.0  0.0
      ...        ...   ...   ...  ...
34995  000135 1997-04-24  NaN    NaN   0.0
34996  000135 1997-04-25  NaN    NaN   4.0
34997  000135 1997-04-26  NaN    22.1  0.0
34998  000135 1997-04-27  31.0   NaN   5.0
34999  000135 1997-04-28  28.8   24.0  0.0
```

I'm counting the NaN values by CODE column, in columns TMAX TMIN and PP. So i'm using this code.

```
dfna=df[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']].isna().groupby(df.CODE).sum()
```

But i want to start counting NaN values since the first non NaN value.

Expected df:

```
CODE   TMAX TMIN PP
000130 2    1    0
000135 0    1    0    
...
...
```

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think in term of  the whole frame, you can use `ffill` to remove the later nan values. So you can use this to detect the nan's that come after the first valid values:

```
df.isna() & df.ffill().notna()
```

Now, you can try `groupby.apply`

```
(df[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']].groupby(df['CODE'])
    .apply(lambda d: (d.isna() & d.ffill().notna()).sum()) 
)
```

Output:

```
      TMAX  TMIN  PP
CODE                
130      2     1   0
135      0     1   0
```

Comment: Not different enough to justify its own answer: `df[cols].isna().groupby(df['CODE']).apply(lambda d: d.sum() - d.to_numpy().argmin(axis=0))`